# Getting ClassNotFoundException for Validator class

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to learn JSF doing a demo project. When I try to add validator to some components, I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.validator.TestValidator

My faces-config looks like this

```
    <validator>
    <validator-id>Validator</validator-id>
    <validator-class>com.test.validator.TestValidator</validator-class>
    </validator>
```

Validator class

```
public class TestValidator implements Validator {


    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent componentToValidate,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        //Add code

    }

}
```

and finally facelet

```
     <f:validator validatorId="Validator"></f:validator>
```

I am not sure if I am missing something. All help are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do you have package declaration in validator class?

Comment: I have added package declaration in validator class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a number of possible causes:

- The TestValidator class is missing a `package` declaration, so you've actually declared it in the default package ... as noted by @Jigar Joshi.
- You haven't compiled it.
- You haven't created / updated the JAR that contains the class.
- You haven't included the JAR in the WAR / EAR.
- The WAR / EAR (or the webserver) is missing the JAR file that contains some class that your TestValidator depends on.  (Seems unlikely ...)
- You haven't redeployed the WAR / EAR.

Comment: I am using Eclipse helios and Glass fish as webserver, so i think most of the issues stated above will be automatically taken care of. Can you guide me on any missing steps. I am sure package declaration is there and the class is compiled.

Comment: Look in the deployed webapp for the JAR file that contains that class, and check that the class is in the JAR file and that its path within the JAR file is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen for the detailed answer and later help. Now its working.